# Convergence in probability of the Fisher information

Tags: statistics, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Given a family $\{\mathbb{P}_\theta\}_{\theta\in\Theta}$ on $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$, where $\Theta\subset\mathbb{R}$ and each member of this family is absolutely continuous w.r.t. $\lambda^1$, and some estimator $\widehat{\theta}_n$ (based on a sample of iid real-valued random variables with distribution within the considered family of measures), I want to prove the following (assuming that all technical assumptions to guarantee that the Fisher information is well-defined are fulfilled):
If there is some $\theta_0\in\Theta$ such that $\widehat{\theta}_n\to\theta_0$ in probability as $n\to\infty$, then $I(\mathbb{P}_{\widehat{\theta}_n})\to I(\mathbb{P}_{\theta_0})$ in probability as $n\to\infty$.
Does someone have an idea how to approach? Thanks in advance!